# TFS 2010 no longer associating changesets with builds

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

Our TFS 2010 server has stopped associating change sets with builds and i cant for the life of me figure out why.

- All the current builds are in a status of 'Build Succeeded'
- the build definition has both the 'associate changesets and work items' and 'label sources' set to true.
- The build goes through just fine

I've checked ...

- the source control history for the solutions and they all have labels assigned associated with the build number
- the diagnostic version of the log shows...

Final Property Values

```
 AgentSettings = Use agent where Name=* and Tags is empty; Max Wait Time: 04:00:00
 AssociateChangesetsAndWorkItems = True
 BuildNumberFormat = IQ_$(Date:yyyyMMdd)$(Rev:.r)
 BuildSettings = Build 2 project(s) for 1 platform(s) and configuration(s)
 CleanWorkspace = All
 CreateLabel = True
 CreateTriggerFileList = False
 CustomArguments =
```

and no errors relating to labels that i can see.

I've tried...

- deleting the build definition and setting it up again

Any help would be appreciated, I'm just not sure where to start looking next.

Thanks

Aidan

Comment: Check history of the DefaultTemplate.xaml (or the template you use). Someone might have change it

Comment: Yes, can you list any customizations you have made to the build process template?  You can very easily break this functionality if you remove too much.  Will respond with an answer after we know which customizations have been made.

Comment: Thanks guys, I reloaded the template from a backup and its all working now ! Now to find the culprit .... !

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Aidan,

You should be looking for the following item in your workflow template:

[image: Associate Changes]

Make sure that this has not been tampered with, and if it has, correct the changes. As others have said, check the history in source control for the workflow template file.